# how to deal with multiple arguments in a dictionary construct when query in sqlalchemy?

Tags: python-2.7, sqlalchemy

In sqlalchemy, I define a function whose argument is a dictionary may contain multiple key-values.I want to query according to the key-values. Here is my program:

```
def get_contact_conditions(kwds):
    for fieldName, fieldValue in kwds.items():
        condition = fieldName + "=:fieldName"
        contact = session.query(Contact).filter(condition).params(fieldName = fieldValue).all()
        session.commit()
        return contact
```

this situation above is when the dictionary has only one key-values, but maybe there are two or three in it, then how to code condition and the values in params(). In another word how to code query clause.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the only comparison you need is "=" then this should work:

```
def get_contact_conditions(kwds):
    contact = session.query(Contact).filter_by(**kwds).all()
    return contact
```

You can read about it here:

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.filter_by

If you need arbitrary operators(<,>,in_,like,etc.) you can pass in a list of sqlalchemy clauses as arguments to the and_ function and pass the result to filter().  These expressions are generated when you compare a model class attribute to something, like:

```
Contact.id < 5
```

So you could do something like this:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import and_

def get_contacts(*exps):
    return session.query(Contact).filter(and_(*exps)).all()

# All contacts with an id less than 5 and a name that starts with user.
contacts = get_contacts(Contact.id < 5, Contact.name.like('user%'))
```

But you should consider that at this point the function is getting closer to just calling session.query directly.

You should read the sqlalchemy docs more to learn about the operators/comparisons that are available on model columns/relations.  There are some really useful ones.

Comment: Tank you and your answer is wonderful. But as you said, when '>' or '<', what to do? @plantian